How to incrementally load data from the bronze to silver layer?
In current on Prem etl we stage incremental data (based on date modified, held in a control table), and UPSERT, that is - update existing records in the final table and insert new records into the final table.
I'm trying to understand what is the approach to do this in a Azure scenario.
For example: say based on a control table I fetch the latest modified data and place it into the bronze layer. Now how do I incrementally load this (UPSERT) into the silver layer?
Note: I'm using Azure data lake gen2, the bronze layer format is parquet, the silver layer format is delta.

Any approach you tried? If yes add blockers you are facing?

Are you using  ADF pipelines or Spark notebooks?

In spark, do a merge statement, you can update and insert using that approach

Here is how you can create the control table with an initial last_processed_date using spark notebooks:
control_table_path = 'abfss://folder02@lambostg.dfs.core.windows.net/control_table'
initial_data = [Row(last_processed_date="2023-09-01")]
control_df = spark.createDataFrame(initial_data)
control_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(control_table_path)
print("Control table created with initial data.")
control_df = spark.read.format("delta").load(control_table_path)
last_processed_date = control_df.collect()[0]["last_processed_date"]
print(f"Last processed date: {last_processed_date}")

Results:
Last processed date: 2023-09-03

As you mentioned you want to implement the Incremental load using (UPSERT) into the silver layer?
I have tried the below approach:
silver_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_table_path)
silver_table.alias("silver").merge(
    incremental_df.alias("bronze"),
    "silver.id = bronze.id"  
).whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
 .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
 .execute()
result_df = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_table_path)
result_df.show()

In the above code loading the Silver Delta table
Performing the UPSERT using MERGE INTO command using the matching condition on id column
Results:
+---+------+---+-------------+
| id|  name|age|last_modified|
+---+------+---+-------------+
|  2|Thomas| 29|   2023-08-26|
|  1| Jerry| 24|   2023-08-25|
+---+------+---+-------------+

